# Not executing commands immediately

Tags: edit-mode

For example, I press left click on the 3D view to change my cursor position. Nothing happens until I do something else, for example zooming in/out.

Also, I press 'T' to hide the tools panel. It just does it after doing something else.

In summary, whatever I do, it gets executed/showed up with "one instruction of delay".

SORY if it's a noob question

**Update:**
I tried Blender 2.7 and Blender 2.79.
Both on Windows 7 64 bits

**Resolved :)**
Now the behaviour is correct, with these Window Drawing Method configs:
Window Draw Method: Full
MultiSample: 2
Region Overlap checkd

Comment: Obviously this is not typical behavior.  No matter how long you wait, it never happens unless you perform another action?  And it always happens as soon as you perform another action?

Comment: Exactly as you tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its normally a problem with the graphic. Check that your graphics drivers are up to date. Also once you have done and if the problem is still there mess with the windows draw settings in user preferences. The settings under system.

Also have a look at these links
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130704213823/http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26691)
https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=28035